# Delete a file while exiting out of the for loop in java

Tags: java, loops, foreach, pdfbox

I created a method that downloads a file from the web, then using a for loop I get the absolute path of that downloaded file and load it into pdfbox to perform further actions. However, I want the file to be automatically deleted when the action is performed. But the code I wrote doesn't allow me to do so. However, if I use the for loop to delete the pdf it works. Any solution?

```
 for (File pdfs : Objects.requireNonNull(folder.listFiles())) {
                String desiredPdf = pdfs.getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println(desiredPdf);
                pdfs.deleteOnExit();
    
                File baseFile = new File(desiredPdf);
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(baseFile);
                document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    
                String pdfContent = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
                System.out.println(pdfContent);
    
                Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Imperfection"));
    
    
            }
```

Comment: Why not load the `PDDocument`s in memory, then you don't need to create/delete files at all?

Comment: Yes, or opening the InputStream you get when downloading from the server. Btw the code above doesn't close the file, don't forget to do this.

Comment: Yes, you're right Tilman. I forgot to close it. Thanks. However, can you elaborate on how to load the `PDDocument` on memory, please? g00se/Tilman

Comment: `PDDocument.load(Files.readAllBytes(pdfs.toPath()))`